# How do you compute $\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Compute the integral
> $$\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}}.$$

I have no idea on how to go about this. I tried factoring it to $(x-1)x(x+1)$ and did $u=x-1$ or $u=x+1$, but it leads to nothing. Trig-sub and hyperbolic sub is impossible because of that 0 in the top bound. Then I tried king's rule and it just makes the problem worse. Is there a sneaky trick to this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This integral can be converted to the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x-x^3}}\tag{1}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}\cdot\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}\tag{2}\\
&=3\int_0^1\frac{y\,dy}{\sqrt[3]{1-y^6}}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1 u^{-2/3}(1-u)^{-1/3}\,du\tag{4}\\
&=\frac12 B\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}.\tag{6}\\
\end{align}$$

$\text{Explanations:}$

$(3)$ Substitute $y=\sqrt[3]x$.

$(4)$ Substitute $u=y^6$.

$(5)$ The definition of the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

$(6)$ A [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas): $B(x,1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $\frac1x=-\sqrt{1+\frac1{t^3}}$

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}}
&=\frac32\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+t^3}\overset{t\to \frac 1t}{dt}
=\frac34\int_0^\infty\frac{1+t}{1+t^3}dt\\
&=\frac34 \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1-t+t^2}dt=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite the integral using some simple substitutions:

$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_{-1}^{0}\left(x^{3}-x\right)^{-1/3}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\left(x-x^{3}\right)^{-1/3}dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}^{3}\right)^{-1/3}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}\right)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-2/3}\left(1-x\right)^{-1/3}dx.
\end{align}
$$

Let $I = J/2$. Define $f: \mathbb{C}^\star \backslash [0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $z \mapsto z^{-2/3} (1-z)^{-1/3}$. We can write $f(z)$ as

$$
f(z) = \exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|z\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\arg z\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-z\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(1-z\right)\right).
$$

To guarantee $f$ is holomorphic on $[0,1)$, we let $\arg z \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\arg(1-z) \in [-\pi,\pi)$. We choose a very small $r$ to denote the gap between the branch cut to the contour. We travel clockwise and integrate along this capsule-shaped path called $C$ [illustrated below](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/anpr6h2x4p).

[image]

We have

$$
\oint_C f(z)dz = \left(\int_{\lambda_1} + \int_{\psi_1} + \int_{\lambda_2} + \int_{\psi_2}\right)f(z)dz.
$$

To retrieve the integral we want, we apply $r \to 0^+$ to each contour integral.

For $\lambda_1$, parameterize $z=x+ir$. As $r \to 0^+$, we have

$$
\begin{align}
J_1 &:= \int_{ir}^{1+ir} f(z)dz\\
&= \int_0^1 f(x+ir)d(x+ir) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|x+ir\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\arg\left(x+ir\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-x-ir\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(1-x-ir\right)\right)dx \\
&\to \int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|x\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\cdot0\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-x\right|-\frac{i}{3}\cdot0\right)dxdx \\
&= J.
\end{align}
$$

Similarly for $\lambda_2$, parameterize $z=x-ir$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
J_2 &:= \int_{1-ir}^{-ir}f(z)dz \\
&= -\int_0^1 f(x-ir)d(x-ir) \\
&= -\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|x-ir\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\arg\left(x-ir\right)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-x+ir\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(1-x+ir\right)\right)dx \\
&\to -\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|x\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\cdot2\pi\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-x\right|-\frac{i}{3}\cdot0\right)dx \\
&= -\exp\left(-\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)J.
\end{align}
$$

For $\psi_1$, parameterize $z=1+re^{-it}$ on $t \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. To prove the integral over $\psi_1$ converges to $0$, we can write $|f(z)|$ like

$$
\begin{align}
|f(z)| &= \left|\exp\left(-\frac{2}{3}\ln\left|z\right|-\frac{2i}{3}\arg z\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|1-z\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(1-z\right)\right)\right| \\
&= \left|\left|1+re^{-it}\right|^{-\frac{2}{3}}\exp\left(-\frac{2i}{3}\arg\left(1+re^{-it}\right)\right)\left|1-1-re^{-it}\right|\exp\left(-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(1-1-re^{-it}\right)\right)\right| \\
&= r\left|1+re^{-it}\right|^{-\frac{2}{3}} \\
&= r\left(r^{2}\sin^{2}t+\left(r\cos t+1\right)^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}. \\
\end{align}
$$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{\psi_1}f(z)dz\right| &= \left|\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}f\left(1+re^{-it}\right)d\left(1+re^{-it}\right)\right| \\
&= \left|-ri \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(z)e^{-it}dt\right| \\
& \leq r \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left|f(z)e^{-it}\right|dt \\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} r^2\left(r^{2}\sin^{2}t+\left(r\cos t+1\right)^{2}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}dt. 
\end{align}
$$

You can use the Squeeze Theorem from there. You can repeat a similar process for the other end of the capsule.

Since the branch cut is encapsulated (pun intended) by the contour and $f$ is holomorphic everywhere else, we can use the Cauchy Deformation Principle to continuously deform the capsule into a large circle with a radius of $\infty$. So

$$
\begin{align}
\oint_C f(z)dz &= 2\pi i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = \infty} f(z) \\
&= -2\pi i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0} \frac{1}{z^2} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\\
&= -2\pi i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0}\frac{1}{z^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \\
&= -2\pi i \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = 0} \frac{1}{z}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|z-1\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(z-1\right)\right) \\
&= -2\pi i \lim_{z \to 0}\left(z-0\right)\cdot\frac{1}{z}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|z-1\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(z-1\right)\right)\\
&= -2\pi i\exp\left(-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left|0-1\right|-\frac{i}{3}\arg\left(-1\right)\right) \\
&= -2\pi i\exp\left(0-\frac{i}{3}\left(-\pi\right)\right) \\
&= -2\pi i\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{3}\right).\\
\end{align}
$$

Hence,
$$
-2\pi i\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{3}\right) = J\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{4\pi i}{3}\right)\right)+0+0
$$
$$
\implies I = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

and we're done!